# TypeError: Object is not a function Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I am writing the following code

```
var http=require('http')

var makerequest=function(message)
{
   var options= {host:'localhost', port:8080, path:'/',method:'POST'}
   var request=http.request(options,function(response)
  {
    response.on('data',function(data)
      {
          console.log(data);
      });
   });
   request.write(message);
   request.end();
}

exports=makerequest;
```

**app.js :**

```
var makerequest=require('./make_request.js');

makerequest("Here's looking at you, kid");
```

I am getting this error

> **TypeError: Object is not a function**

Can someone help on this.I tried searching but couldnt find a solution. Thanks

Comment: which line throws that error?

Comment: `module.exports` not `exports`.

Comment: was about to answer but Andy got it,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` returns an object which references the value of `module.exports` for a given file. You should use `module.exports` instead of `exports` in your code instead.

You can find [more information here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) on the differences between the two.

Comment: The previous error is gone.There is new error that says:
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:983:19)

Comment: @user2201629, that's a completely different question, I'm afraid. Mark this as answered and then add a new question.